# SQL Service Broker Simulate a Poison Message

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, service-broker

I am reading an expert from a google preview book.
[shorturl.at/htF38](https://shorturl.at/htF38)

I want to basically simulate a poision message in a Service Broker Queue.
The author presents this code fragment to simulate 5 rollbacks .

My question is how does this pieces of code simulate 5 rollbacks beats me.

Per me On line 31 if it does not see a message in the queue the rollback happens once
and the break statement breaks the loop no ?

```
DECLARE @ch UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
DECLARE @messagetypename NVARCHAR(256)
DECLARE @messagebody XML

WHILE (1=1)

BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        WAITFOR (
        RECEIVE TOP (1)
        @ch = conversation_handle,
        @messagetypename = message_type_name,
        @messagebody = CAST(message_body AS XML)
        FROM TargetQueue
        ), 
        TIMEOUT 60000

    IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
    BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    BREAK **--Line No 31**
    END
    -- Rolling back the current transaction
PRINT 'Rollback the current transaction - simulating a poison message...'
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
GO
```

Now, when you place a message into the TargetQueue and execute the service program
shown in Listing ,you'll see that Service Broker deactivates the queue automatically, and
you’ll get an error message

Comment: `WHILE (1 = 1)` executes forever, until the `BREAK`, which happens only if the `WAITFOR (RECEIVE...)` yields no rows, which happens only if the queue is deactivated. Effectively it simulates rolling back until SQL Server deactivates the queue; how many times that takes is left to SQL Server.

Comment: Hi Jeroen Thanks for the comment But lets say the queue has zero rows then i think the loop will rollback only once no ?

Comment: If the queue has no messages at all, the `WAITFOR` will just sit there for 60 seconds blissfully doing nothing. So yes, if the queue is empty then after 60 seconds this should stop without doing anything. Arguably the whole thing is clearer if the `TIMEOUT` clause is just removed so it waits forever.

Comment: Hi Jeroen how does the author claim then that this TSQL batch can simulate a poison message is what i am clueless about.The author has made his code available at shorturl.at/bkqMP

Comment: Well presumably you're *supposed* to either start with a non-empty queue, or start this and then insert a message within 60 seconds of starting this. When you do that this will dutifully start receiving and rolling back forever, until poison message handling steps in or you get bored (if poison message handling is disabled, which is an option from SQL Server 2008 R2 onwards). I have not studied the linked code in detail or attempted to run it, but it might be expected to leave a message in the queue for this loop to process (or else the book has more details on this).

Comment: Thank You So much Jeroen I appreciate your help :).